# Are religious beliefs inherently self-contradictory?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

Religious people practice compassion, generosity, and altruism to save themself of eternal suffering in the afterlife.

**Isn't that behaviour motivated by pure self-interest?.**

Also most religions condemn in one way or another self-indulgent and egotistical behaviours, but encourage their followers to practice altruism when it comes to their own salvation.

**Aren't they being egotistical and egocentric behaving in that way?**

Comment: Why do you think that religions "need them to do" egoistic things to "save themselves"? Isn't compassion and generosity and altruism always a topic?

Comment: @iphigenie If they practice compassion and generosity and altruism to save themself of eternal suffering in the afterlife, aren't they being egotistical and egocentric?

Comment: By the way, if you don't understand the question, please don't down-vote it, just post a comment.

Comment: Can you share a little more about what you might be reading or studying that may have motivated this question -- and maybe a little about what the specific problem you're encountering, what hypotheses you may have formed, what your research may have turned up? What exactly would you like someone here to explain to you...?

Comment: @rraallvv That is an entirely different question than what your headline's asking. So it's not about the logic of religions, but about the value of seemingly altruistic acts? But that wouldn't belong here. Vote to close until further clarification of the matter.

Comment: @JosephWeissman There seems to me that the answer is yes, religious beliefs are mostly self contradictory, but then that is not what religious people take into acount whey they join a religion.

Comment: I concur with iphigenie on the discrepancy between the title and the question.

Answer (score 4):

This question seems like some sort of flame-bait, but there's a long history of a similar type of question about certain types of ethical views (though I don't see much to suggest you have that in mind, I will answer assuming there's a real question there). Specifically, this challenge has been raised by [Knud Ejler Løgstrup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knud_Ejler_L%C3%B8gstrup) towards Søren Kierkegaard's *Works of Love*. To state the accusation in more detail, we need to understand as a rough sketch what Kierkegaard is suggesting in the earlier part of the text.

In rough outline, Kierkegaard suggests that we love God and then love people . The things we do for others are "works of love" that express our love for God.  God also guarantees us eternal life (in Kierkegaard's theology). Thus, the accusation is that doing loving things for others is just a way to get patted on the back. A similar critique is also raised by Theodor Adorno.

There's a significant amount of scholarship that argues against this critique. Most of this centers on clarifying what is meant by expressing our love for God in acts of love for others. One key is not seeing love as bifurcated such that you can only love one or the other. (I can love my wife and my brother without that being a contradiction). A second element is to see how love for one person can motivate love for another. (e.g., loving my brother could extend to loving my brother's children).

Obviously, a slight variation on the accusation involves deleting the significance of the attributes of God and God inspiring love in the self. Doing so makes it a weird fantasy where the person enjoys doing good things for no reason out of self-love. (The observation can also be reversed and put on atheists -- accusing them of the same sort of selfishness for imagining there's good to do).

I could delve more into the textual details, but I think this suffices to express your worry in more philosophical terms and to explain at least one route of *trying* to defend against it open to theists.

Comment: Buddhism advocates the ['cessation of deed'](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/study/kamma.html#notbnotw), i.e. not being a busybody, while simultaneously advocating [love and compassion, etc.](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nyanaponika/wheel006.html).  It's kind of like being nice but not chasing after wind.

Comment: and that relates to my answer how???

Comment: You mention "doing loving things" and loving as if they are inseparable while that is actually what is advocated in Buddhism, and I'd dare say in Ecclesiastes as chasing after wind.  Part of the idea is that acts can be misguided.  I think there's also some idea that necessity is dealt with without intention.  Just dealing with today without busying about tomorrow.  "Works of love" seems to fly straight against "cessation of deed" and it might be interesting to see the roots of the contradiction.

Comment: No, I mention doing loving things as part of an interpretation of Kierkegaard who wrote a book called *Works of Love* based around titular concept. Regardless of what Buddhism thinks about the ideas involved, my answer isn't randomly pulling ideas out of a hat but rather following a string of related ideas.

Comment: Actually it connects together very well. From [your link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knud_Ejler_Løgstrup#The_Ethical_Demand): "[The ethical] demand ultimately turns out to be unfulfillable for Løgstrup in the sense that “what is demanded is that the demand should not have been necessary.”"  This fits very well with Buddhism's cessation of deed and continued compassionateness.  Everything necessary is attended to out of basic care.  Anything on top is chasing after wind.

Comment: I'm not denying the two are *relatable*; I'm denying the necessity of drawing out the relation in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I do not claim that the following analogy provides all or any of the answers, but I hope that it's helpful in reflecting further on the question at hand.

A child does things to/for his/her parents out of love. Yet a child also gets reward and/or punishment that is dependant on behaviour.

This isn't a paradox. A child's intent to do something could be love, regardless of the reward/punishment system being in place. The reward/punishment system is there to stop the child from ever acting on malicious intent (hopefully, the lack of action leads to the eventual disinterest and forgetting of it). A child's intent could also be reward. If the parent is savvy enough, the parent will pick up on the child's selfish intent and not give the child the reward at all. The punishment is there to prevent problems from starting or getting bigger. Sometimes children need a push until they are able to grow up and realize for themselves why certain things aren't allowed. On the other hand, the reward system seems to be the parent's way of showing love. Rewards are given, because the parent wants the child to be happy. They aren't excessively given so as not to spoil the child, have the child take things for granted, or have the child feel entitled to whatever he/she wants, including his/her own rules.

Answer (score 1):

Some religious flavours are not motivated by egoism in the way you describe.  Here is an example from the Lankavatara Sutra --"notably an important sūtra in Chinese Chán and its Japanese version, Zen" - Wikipedia :-

> "There are three attachments that are especially deep-seated in the
>   minds of all: greed, anger and infatuation, which are based on lust,
>   fear and pride. Back of these lies discrimination and desire which is
>   procreative and is accompanied with excitement and avariciousness and
>   love of comfort and desire for eternal life; and, following, is a
>   succession of rebirths on the five paths of existence and a
>   continuation of attachments. But if these attachments are broken off,
>   no signs of attachment nor of detachment will remain because they are
>   based on things that are non-existent; when this truth is clearly
>   understood the net of attachment is cleared away."

quoted from The Lankavatara Sutra, [A Buddhist Bible](http://sacred-texts.com/bud/bb/bb14.htm), page 112.

A similar sentiment comes through from Ecclesiastes [1 xiv](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ecclesiastes%201&version=ESV) & [2 xxiv](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ecclesiastes%202&version=ESV) :-

> "I have seen everything that is done under the sun, and behold, all is
>   vanity and a striving after wind."
>
> "There is nothing better for a person than that he should eat and drink and find enjoyment in his toil. ..."

Some texts work better for others.  There is a developmental journey.